# Why does a CW-complex consist of *open* cells?

Tags: general-topology, geometric-topology

[Wikipedia states](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex)

> A CW complex is a Hausdorff space X together with a partition of X into open cells (of perhaps varying dimension) that satisfies two additional properties:
>
> 1. For each n-dimensional open cell C in the partition of X, there exists a continuous map f from the n-dimensional closed ball to X such that
>
>    - The restriction of f to the interior of the closed ball is a homeomorphism onto the cell C, and
>
>      - the image of the boundary of the closed ball is contained in the union of a finite number of elements of the partition, each having cell dimension less than n.
> 2. A subset of X is closed if and only if it meets the closure of each cell in a closed set.

I am confused by this definition, because I don't see how for example a torus is a CW complex (I've been told it is), given that the cells have to be open.

Here's my problem: I'd consider a torus to consist of one open 2-cell (the image of an open square/disk onto the main shape of the torus), and two 1-cells, namely the left and right side of the square glued together and the top and bottom sides glued together.

**The problem with this is, because the sides have to be open cells, we havent included the corners of the square**. If we would include that, it wouldn't be an open cell anymore. So in this construction, either one or two points of the torus are not included in the partitioning into cells.

**What mistake am I making?**

Comment: The corners are $0$-cells...

Comment: @YuiToCheng, oohhh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

each open cell is open *in its own dimension*. So an open 0-cell is a point. let's call our point $v$. If you glue two closed 1-balls, call them $a$ and $b$ (closed interval) onto $v$ along their boundary, we get a wedge of two circles, where the basepoint is $v$ (and the endpoints of the intervals are also $v$). Thus the *open* 1-cell $a$ is homeomorphic to an *open* petal of the rose (so take away $v$).

Finally, glue in a closed $2$-ball (a disk) so that the boundary of the $2$ disk traces out $abAB$, where implicitly I have chosen an orientation of $a$ and $b$ and indicated $A$ as meaning tracing out $A$ in the reverse orientation. From my description it may not be obvious that the CW-complex you get is a torus, but I claim that it is.

The schematic is this. Draw a square, label the corners (0-cells) $v$, and then label and orient the edges $a$ and $b$ so that starting at the initial vertex of an $a$ edge and walking forward around the square we read $a$, then $b$, then $a$ with the opposite orientation and $b$ with the opposite orientation. Now glue oriented edges together. You should get a torus!